# How to send the reference field value from SOQL result in apex to Aura component

Tags: apex, javascript, aura

I have a custom solution to export the product line items(custom object) into CSV file, i want to include one of the field(EAN__c) value from product(product line item is having lookup relationship to product), But when i query list of product line items from apex and try to send the list to component, it is not fetching the reference field(EAN__c) values from the parent object. I thought of putting it in wrapper class and send that wrapper list, can any one please let me know how can i put the list of product line items in wrapper class.

controller class:

```
    public class downloadWrapper{               
    public OpportunityProduct__c attributes;
    public String EAN;
}
/* Export data into csv file  */
@AuraEnabled
public static list <OpportunityProduct__c> fetchLineItems(Id oppId){      
    List<OpportunityProduct__c> returnOppList = [SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity__c, Product__c,Product__r.EAN__c, ReferenceProduct__c, Quantity__c, UnitPrice__c, IsWon__c, TotalPrice__c, MPOPrice__c, StartOfDelivery__c, EndOfDelivery__c, Branding__c, Delivered__c, Description__c From OpportunityProduct__c Where Opportunity__c = :oppId];
    system.debug('returnOppList===>'+returnOppList);
    return returnOppList;
}
```

JS helper class:

```
     onLoad: function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get('c.fetchLineItems');
    action.setParams({
        oppId : component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set('v.ListOfLineItems', response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
```

Thanks,
Anitha

Comment: There's no need to use a wrapper class to get to the data. However, depending on how you're using it, you'll need to do some post-processing in your Aura component. This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question. You need to ask about your X, not the Y.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a permissions issue. Does the running user have visibility to the Product object and the `EAN__c`field? I agree with the above, there should be no need to involve a wrapper class here.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox/nbrown - That means i need to do some changes on my component side in order capture EAN__c field value right. But in the JS helper i kept the debug logs to check the response from apex controller it is giving the result like this.                             debug log for response received on JS Helper => response from server ==>SecureAction: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }  ///==> How can i see received response has EAN?

Comment: Hi, i got it i have written some condition on my component side that that solved my issue. i got the EAN__c value with below code in my helper:                                          if( skey === 'Product__r'){
                   
                    csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].EAN__c+'"';
                }

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify() to see the output

Comment: Yes, Sunil i have used the same and got the output. Thanks.